# Regex Pattern for domain or hostnames or probably the best way to match a pattern

Tags: arrays, regex, ruby

Here's a sample domain name FQDN, How can I match the domain name after the short hostname? instead of making a pattern match for domain names? Advice is really much appreciated.

```
host1.dept1.domain.com
host2.domain.com
host3.domain3.com
```

Comment: What is the expected output? What did you try so far? Did you consider using a URL parse or URL library when working with URLs?

Comment: Please see "[ask]" and the linked pages and "[mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)".
Did you research this? Where? If it didn't help tell us why. What did you try? If you didn't try, why not? If you did, what did you do? We'd like to see your minimal attempt to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something to consider:

```
require 'fruity'

nodes = %w[
  host1.dept1.domain.com
  host2.domain.com
  host3.domain3.com
]

def your_way_gsub(listnode)
  nodes = []
  listnode.each do |listnodes|
    nodes << listnodes.gsub(/^(?:[\w]+)(.)/, '')
  end
  nodes
end

def your_way_sub(listnode)
  nodes = []
  listnode.each do |listnodes|
    nodes << listnodes.sub(/^(?:[\w]+)(.)/, '')
  end
  nodes
end

def my_way_split_join(ary)
  ary.map { |s|
    s.split('.')[1..-1].join('.')
  }
end

def my_way_regex(ary)
  ary.map { |s|
    s[/^[^.]+\.(.+)$/, 1]
  }
end
```

Check to see they're doing the right thing:

```
your_way_gsub(nodes)     # => ["dept1.domain.com", "domain.com", "domain3.com"]
your_way_sub(nodes)      # => ["dept1.domain.com", "domain.com", "domain3.com"]
my_way_split_join(nodes) # => ["dept1.domain.com", "domain.com", "domain3.com"]
my_way_regex(nodes)      # => ["dept1.domain.com", "domain.com", "domain3.com"]
```

And run a benchmark:

```
compare do
  _your_way_gsub { your_way_gsub(nodes) }
  _your_way_sub { your_way_sub(nodes) }
  _my_way_split_join { my_way_split_join(nodes) }
  _my_way_regex { my_way_regex(nodes) }
end

# >> Running each test 2048 times. Test will take about 1 second.
# >> _my_way_regex is faster than _your_way_sub by 19.999999999999996% ± 10.0%
# >> _your_way_sub is faster than _my_way_split_join by 39.99999999999999% ± 10.0%
# >> _my_way_split_join is faster than _your_way_gsub by 2x ± 0.1
```

Hostnames, by [definition](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/hostname.7.html), can include `a`..`z`, `0`..`9`, `.` and `-`:

> Each element of the hostname must be from 1 to 63 characters long and the entire hostname, including the dots, can be at most 253 characters long.  Valid characters for hostnames are ASCII(7) letters from a to z, the digits from 0 to 9, and the hyphen (-).  A hostname may not start with a hyphen.

Your code barfs on the hyphen if the name is something like `"legal-hostname.domain.tld"` because `\w` actually means `[a-z0-9_]` in regex-ese:

> `/\w/ - A word character ([a-zA-Z0-9_])`

```
nodes = %w[
  legal-hostname.domain.tld
]

your_way_gsub(nodes)     # => ["hostname.domain.tld"]
your_way_sub(nodes)      # => ["hostname.domain.tld"]
my_way_split_join(nodes) # => ["domain.tld"]
my_way_regex(nodes)      # => ["domain.tld"]
```

[`gsub`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/String.html#method-i-gsub) and [`sub`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/String.html#method-i-sub) are similar, but, given the same pattern and input string, `gsub` will always run one more iteration searching for any additional matches. In a short string being searched once that's not a big deal, but in a big string or iterating over many strings that can make a big difference. Don't use `gsub` as a catch-all, because it isn't. Both tools have a place in the toolbox and using the wrong one can cause problems.

Regular expressions are a wonderful thing, but they're not a golden hammer to hit every task we want to do. The engine is flexible and patterns can be a great time saver when we're taking apart strings but you have to test and benchmark carefully because a poorly written pattern can open up holes in your code that are very hard to diagnose, or worse, can cause your code to slow to a crawl because the engine isn't being told how to scan efficiently.

That said, the richness of patterns are worth studying. You can do some amazing things with them, but always try different ways of accomplishing the same task and don't assume one is faster, check.

See "[Regular Expressions: Now You Have Two Problems](https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/)" for a nice discussion. See Ruby's [Regexp documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Regexp.html) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I've resolve my issues. No Im not parsing from URL, I just wanted the pattern after the shortname then inserting it back to an array by replacing the matched with blank or whitespace after the . So i can get the value after it.

```
          @listnode = connector.nodes.list
          @listnode.each do |listnodes|
            nodes << listnodes.gsub(/^(?:[\w]+)(.)/, '')
          end
          puts nodes
```

The result is:

From:

```
host1.dept1.domain.com
host2.domain.com
host3.domain3.com
```

To:

```
dept1.domain.com
domain.com
domain3.com
```

Comment: Don't use `gsub` when `sub` will suffice. `sub` is faster. But I'd use `'host1.dept1.domain.com'.split('.')[1..-1].join('.') # => "dept1.domain.com"`

Comment: Very cool! thank you @theTinMan. I really do appreciate it. Let me try refactor and get back to you.